# Pinterest. data-pin-description didn't work on my website

Tags: html, css, pinterest

For some purposes I need to have different text on my title\alt on images and on Pinterest pin.

I'm trying to add data-pin-description data attr to images on my website, and in two places it works perfect, but on a third place it didn't work. I tried to remove alt\title from this image but it don't do any changes. Is there any idea why this attribute don't work on my page?

Comment: I noticed, that if you're using data-pin-media on the image, i.e. you're loading other image for pinning AND if you're trying to pin with buttonBookmark (all images), then this version of Save button triggers pinmarklet.js which for some reason ignores the description of your alternative image.